# Read disk of distroless container in Kubernetes for debugging

Tags: kubernetes, azure-kubernetes-service

I am using a helm chart, which deploys containers based on [Distroless](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless).
This means, I cannot open a shell on these containers, like I normally would for debugging, since Distroless containers seem to have no shell command.

```
$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty $POD -n $NAMESPACE -- /bin/sh
error: Internal error occurred: error executing command in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "ded18296c4c0008c29a165ac761f73e3bbabcb068936b4b6efd2bcd686aa8930": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown
```

I also tried using the `kubectl debug` command, but get the following error:

```
$ kubectl debug -it $POD -n $NAMESPACE --image alpine    
error: ephemeral containers are disabled for this cluster (error from server: "the server could not find the requested resource")
```

This is on an Azure Kubernetes cluster, and I could not find an option to enable "ephemeral containers".

For debugging, I would like to read a log file that is written by the container, but not exposed to standard output.
How can I do this in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

> which deploys containers based on Distroless

Using Distroless is a good practice! This typically means that you don't have more than the absolute minimum in your container to run your application - it is typically just your application and some necessary libraries. This also means that there are no extra tools and debugging possibilities within the container - which is good in a production environment for security and maintainability reasons.

> This means, I cannot open a shell on these containers, like I normally would for debugging

To be able to use debugging or other tools in a container based on Distroless, you can build the same container with e.g. Ubuntu as base image. To be able to do this, you typically need the `Dockerfile`, so that you can change how the container is built.